# How to add Qt header files that located outside of source directory to moc list?

Tags: scons

I have some problem with header files that are located outside of app source directory. My project directory structure:

```
/prj
    /include
        slon.h
        ...
    /src
        /app
            slon.cpp
            ...
        /lib1
        /lib2
        ...
    SConstruct
```

Source files are in 'prj/src/app' and common headers located at 'prj/include'. Some of the headers shall be moced because contain Q_OBJECT macro. In qmake these headers added explicitly as sources. In SCons, as I understand it, such headers should not be added explicitly - SCons scans sources and derive appropriate headers automatically. But this works only for headers that located in the same directory with source file. If the header file is in 'prj/include' directory, then SCons does not moc the header. In above example file 'slon.h' contains class with Q_OBJECT macro and is included in 'slon.cpp' but not moced, just ignored.

How can I force SCons to moc headers that are located in separate directory?

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, the default Qt Tool (designed for Qt3 projects) from the core sources of *SCons* doesn't offer a solution for this. You could write your own Builder, of course...

The separately developed Qt4 and Qt5 Tools (see [the SCons ToolIndex](https://bitbucket.org/scons/scons/wiki/ToolsIndex), and follow the corresponding links) provide an

```
ExplicitMoc4(target, source)
```

and

```
ExplicitMoc5(target, source)
```

Builder, respectively. These should help you in all those cases where the "Automoc" feature fails.

Comment: Yes, I'm using your pretty tool SCons_Qt5 from the very beginning of my scons + qt work, thank you very much! I've tried to use ExplicitMoc5 and found out the following: the simple 'ExplicitMoc5( MocTarget, MocHeader )' creates correct *.cc and *.o files in build dir, but these files not linked. If I add 'Program( Target, Sources + MocTarget )' the tool creates 'moc_<name>.cc' and 'moc_name.o' files in 'include' dir and both *.o files are passed to linker that causes redeclaration error. What is the correct way to use 'ExplicitMoc5'?

Comment: That's difficult to tell...without having a concrete example to work on. It sounds like you're also trying to use the "variant dir" feature at the same time. If this assumption is correct, please try whether "duplicate=1" in all SConscript calls fixes things for you. If not, please create a MWE and add it to your question. Preferably create a completely new question on SO, or write to the [SCons User mailing list](http://scons.org/lists.html).

Comment: Yes, I'm using "variant_dir"... Seems I could get success with ExplicitMoc5. The problems were due to incorrect path definitions for target and source nodes - I've tried to construct path strings using env.Dir() which returns different values in different contexts. Correct path values for target and source nodes solve the problem. ExplicitMoc5 works fine. Thank you very much once more!